# Проблема с демаршалингом XML файла в JAXB

Tags: java, xml, парсер, jaxb

Собственно маршалинг и сохранение XML файла проходит успешно, а вот загрузка и демаршалинг выдаёт ошибку. Ошибка возникает в методе unmarshal().

**Сам класс-объект:**

```
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType (propOrder = {"startCity", "finishCity", "distance"})
public class Routes {

    private final StringProperty startCity;
    private final StringProperty finishCity;
    private final IntegerProperty distance;

    public Routes(String startCity, String finishCity, Integer distance) {
        this.startCity = new SimpleStringProperty(startCity);
        this.finishCity = new SimpleStringProperty(finishCity);
        this.distance = new SimpleIntegerProperty(distance);
    }

    public String getStartCity() {
        return startCity.get();
    }

    public StringProperty startCityProperty() {
        return startCity;
    }

    public void setStartCity(String startCity) {
        this.startCity.set(startCity);
    }

    public String getFinishCity() {
        return finishCity.get();
    }

    public StringProperty finishCityProperty() {
        return finishCity;
    }

    public void setFinishCity(String finishCity) {
        this.finishCity.set(finishCity);
    }

    public int getDistance() {
        return distance.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty distanceProperty() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(int distance) {
        this.distance.set(distance);
    }

}
```

**Класс обёртка:**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;


@XmlRootElement (name = "routes")
public class ListRoutesWrapper {

    private List<Routes> routes;

    @XmlElement (name = "route")
    public List<Routes> getRoutes() {
        return routes;
    }

    public void setRoutes(List<Routes> routes) {
        this.routes = routes;
    }
```

**Загрузка и сохранение:**

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import java.io.File;


public class ListRoutes {

    private File file = new File("C:\\routes.xml");

    private ObservableList<Routes> listRoutes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList<Routes> getListRoutes() {
        return listRoutes;
    }

    public File getRoutesFilePath() {
        return file;
    }

    public void addListRoutes(Routes route) {
        listRoutes.add(route);
    }

    public void removeListRoutes(int selectedItem) {
        listRoutes.remove(selectedItem);
    }

    public void loadRouteDataFromFile(File file) { // Демаршалинг
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance(ListRoutesWrapper.class);
            Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

     ListRoutesWrapper wrapper = (ListRoutesWrapper) um.unmarshal(file); // ОШИБКА ВОЗНИКАЕТ ЗДЕСЬ

            listRoutes.clear();
            listRoutes.addAll(wrapper.getRoutes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("Could not load data");
            alert.setContentText("Could not load data from file:\n" + file.getPath());

            alert.showAndWait();

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void saveRouteDataToFile(File file) { // Маршаллируем и сохраняем XML в файл
        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                    .newInstance(ListRoutesWrapper.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            ListRoutesWrapper wrapper = new ListRoutesWrapper();
            wrapper.setRoutes(listRoutes);

            m.marshal(wrapper, file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("Could not save data");
            alert.setContentText("Could not save data to file:\n" + file.getPath());

            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }
}
```

**XML файл после сохранения:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

<routes>
 <route>
   <startCity>Пермь</startCity>
   <finishCity>Ижевск</finishCity>
   <distance>210</distance>
 </route>
</routes>
```

**Ошибка:**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: model.Routes.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory.create0(ClassFactory.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.createInstance(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:270)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.createInstance(UnmarshallingContext.java:684)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.startElement(StructureLoader.java:171)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:559)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:153)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:380)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2787)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:243)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:162)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:171)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:189)
at model.ListRoutes.loadRouteDataFromFile(ListRoutes.java:43)
at controller.RouteAddController.initialize(RouteAddController.java:52)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
```

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: model.Routes.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)` как бы намекает, что не плохо было бы определить конструктор в классе Routes

Answer (score 0):

Надо поставить

```
@XmlElement (name = "route")
public void setRoutes(List<Routes> routes) {
    this.routes = routes;
}
```